# Why aren't my images displaying in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

A client has made a point that some images are not working when viewing through Microsoft Edge, but work perfectly find using Chrome, firefox even old version of IE:

Microsoft Edge it display like this:
[image]

my code is quite simple:

```css
.card .staff_pic {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.card .linkedin-icon {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.card {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  float: left
}
.card_content {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -400px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  color: #fff
}
.card_content h3 {
  font-size: 28px;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.card_content p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}
.card:hover .card_content {
  background-color: rgba(151, 145, 59, 0.8);
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img class="staff_pic alignnone size-medium wp-image-4306" src="../wp-content/uploads/2014/10/David.png" alt="David" />
  <div class="card_content">
    <h3>David Durham</h3>
    Head of Bid Management &amp; Consultancy Services
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img class="linkedin-icon alignnone size-full wp-image-4321" src="../wp-content/uploads/2014/10/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" width="37" height="36" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: corrected the link

Comment: It's working fine for me in Edge. If this is in a live site, can you post the url?

Comment: http://www.carleyconsult.co.uk/about-us/ is the address that apparently there are issues with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inspected the element in Edge and your `<p>` and `<img>` elements are being rendered as:

```
<p>
    <img class="staff_pic alignnone size-medium wp-image-4310" alt="Jim" &nbsp;src="http://www.carleyconsult.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Jim.png">
</p>
```

Note the `&nbsp;` in there. This is causing the element to break. It's correctly rendering in Chrome, so I suspect Edge is doing something weird. One fix would be to run a jQuery script to search of your `<img>` elements to find the `&nbsp;` and remove it. It's not an ideal solution, but I can't think of a better one off the top of my head. At least it's one while looking for another!

Comment: Ahhh that make sence I have a jquery script to find all the p tags and put a &nbsp; to the second to last word so that I dont have any ophan words, disabled it and it works cheers.